# Implement Single Sign On (SSO) using offline cookie in Keycloak

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak

Can we implement Single Sign On (SSO) using offline cookie in Keycloak ?

I have **application 'A '** connected to Keycloak 7.0.1 (KC) server for authentication.  KC generates the active session and offline session for user under '**clientA**' and returns access token & offline token to user. Offline token has validity of say X days. So when user tries connecting to application 'A" again it uses offline cookie to get the access token and user gets authenticated. So authentication is working using that offline cookie for Application 'A'.

Now I have another **application 'B'** , lets say it is hosted on same or different domain.  KC is able to access the same offline cookie but it doesn't allow the authentication. The client for this application is **'client B'**.  The error which I get is **"Session doesn’t have required client"**

Looking at error and reading at articles I understood that two different clients cannot access same offline cookie. But still I wanted to know do anyone came across this scenario and  what was the way used to allow both the applications to use same offline cookie or does we have any keycloak configuration which is missing .

Editing this question:
Can we have any REALM level Offline Token instead of creating different offline tokens for each client in realm ?

Answer (score 0):

The keycloak is there to generate the credentials for the different applications, you need to create a second client in the same realm for the application b (you say you have already done that).

I do not think that you can use the access token from application a to application b. Maybe you could do that depending in the way that you generate the token if the two applications share the same private key, but if you do that then probably you do not need keycloak.

Then make an authorization request in this client, since you already have a session in keycloak this should happen automatically and generate the credentials that you need for application b.

To see if this works correctly, I would try to login directly in application b, go to keycloak, login there and see if the token provided can log me in application b.

Sorry for the high level response, but your question is also quite high level itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know my question is little high level sorry for it. But I wanted to know is it possible to create the offline token on REALM Level instead of creating them on client level. I didn' t got anyway to do this but if you have any idea about this then please let me know .

Comment: it is what I say in my answer, you can do that by having the applications sharing the same private key to generate the token. But then you do not need keycloak probably.